# How will add global variable in velocity template html so that global variable to reset to initial values

Tags: java, html, pdf, velocity, velocity-template-language

Example:
Initial currentpageNo is 1 in velocity context.

## set($currentpageNo=$currentpageNo+1)

$currentpageNo

For each page

Current page value is 2

But require is it should increase.

Please let me know if there is any possiable way

Comment: You will need to handle it in Java code, how do you use/call velocity template from Java?